# Can I save iCloud documents to the Documents folder as well as to iCloud?

Tags: macos, finder, icloud, pages

Basically, I want to be able to save a copy of my iCloud documents that I made in Pages (on both mac and iOS) to my documents folder, where all my pre-iCloud documents are still stored. 

to note: I still want to be able to save a pages document to iCloud, but I would like to have a way of getting to them from the documents folder.

 I hope that makes sense :)

 Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to sync your Documents folder and iCloud documents?

Comment: Sounds to me like they want to have the iCloud equivalent of "offline documents". Which, as far as I understand, is how iCloud works anyway. You save it to the "iCloud" destination, and it ensures that you've got a version backed up in the cloud.

Comment: When I save something to iCloud, the only way that I know of to open it is to start pages and hope that the `open from iCloud` box appears, or by going to ‘File -> Open Recent’. So basically what I want is a way to access the documents stored in iCloud (since I also use the mobile pages app) from my documents folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a document to as many places as you like by using "Save As". There is nothing special about iCloud on that level, it's just another "place" you can select in the Open/Save dialog.